# How to parse data from a http based api every few seconds?

Tags: php, rest, curl

So I've tried to find the answer from various sources but can't find the exact answer to this. Basically, I am currently using cURL to get data from an external domain which offers Http GET. Now I want to call this HTTP GET url every few seconds, in fact I want to call a few hundred of such URLs every few seconds. What would be the best way to go about it? I'm comfortable with php but willing to learn any new solutions that can come.

Answer (score 0):

Under linux this can be achieved easlisy with a cron job.

Equivalent solutions exist for windows.

Comment: Cron jobs generally have a minimum limit of a minute, also I want to get simultaneous responses for ex: www.example.com/api?=hello1, www.example.com/api?=hello2, www.example.com/api?=hello3 etc